# Can't make new app in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to add my first iOS app to iTunes Connect, but when I try, it shows me this message:

```
You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps.
Register one here.
```

with a link to the [Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles page](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleCreate.action).

I already have a wildcard App ID, as well as a certificate and provisioning profile. Am I doing anything wrong here? I have searched other questions with the same error message, but to no avail.

Edit: In case it wasn't clear above, I have already made an App ID. I also tried it with an explicit app ID, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Pls go through this, wildcard App ID vs. an explicit App ID: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1713/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

WildCard App Id is only allowed for development but for putting it on app store, you need to have fixed unique app id.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard app id option is only for development purposes. When publishing on the app store, you need to provide a unique app id, such as **com.company.appname**.  Go to the [App Ids page](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle) directly to create one, or from the link you posted, Identifiers -> App IDs on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Login with your apple developer account here https://developer.apple.com/account/

And add new Bundle ID for your app and then open itunes connect and add new app.